# How to configure dynamic value on @OpenAPIDefinition using Micronaut

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, micronaut

Is it possible to have dynamic values on @OpenAPIDefinition?

- This setup in Micronaut openapi is currently working, we can display the version and server context-path:

  In Application.class:

  @OpenAPIDefinition(
  info = @Info(title = "${info.title}", description = "${info.description}",version  ="${info.version}"), servers = {@Server(url ="${server.context-path}")}


  In openapi.properties

[image]

My objectives are:

1. I want to use the "micronaut.server.context-path" value from application.properties

   if I use "micronaut.server.context-path", it just take it as string literal, as is not the real property value
2. I want to use the "build.version" value from build-info.properties

    I also want to use the "build.version", but I didn't how I can reference that in micronaut